# ASP.NET Core self hosted always running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, server, web-hosting

I have a ASP.NET Core application (based on abp.io but I don't think it is relevant here.

This application is self-hosted and needs to be always running because it has background works that needs to be done even during night, when there are no connection. However, it seems that the self-hosted server goes down during this time: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Workers#making-your-application-always-run.

I found here https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#making-asp-net-core-application-always-running-on-iis that we can configure IIS to be always running and I think it is what I need.

The problem is that I can't host my a pplication on IIS for now. Is there an alternative for self-hosted version (the .exe running)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're just running the exe, what makes you say your application is "going down"? Do you mean it crashes, or what?

Comment: My application has some background workers (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Workers). They save data to my database regularilly. When I browse my web site, I can see the results in the database. The next day, when I open the application again, I can see results for the next day until around 2h after I went home, and results since I browsed the application again, but no results during the night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw it was not a problem linked to my application but to the Operating System. I installed [caffeine](https://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) and now my application does not stop working and always run its background workers